# $\pm A$ is sectorial implies it is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, semigroup-of-operators

The question is as follows: suppose $(A,D(A))$ is a sectorial operator on a Banach space $X$ such that $-A$ is sectorial as well, prove that $A$ must be bounded.

Since I’ve found there are many more or less equivalent conventions on sectoriality I’ll state the one I’m more familiar with:
$A$ is sectorial if the sector

$\Sigma(\omega,\theta):=\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}| \;\;|\arg(\omega-z)|<\theta\right\}$

is contained in the resolvent set $\rho(A)$, where $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\theta\in\left(\frac {\pi}2,\pi\right)$ and

$\forall z\in\Sigma(\omega,\theta)\;\;\; ||R(z,A)||\leq M|z|^{-1},$

for some positive constant $M$.

It is straightforward to show that if $\pm A$ is sectorial then the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is bounded. Now, I have two strategies in my mind that I cannot conclude:

1. Showing that the generated Analytic Semigroup is actually Uniformly Continuous, since I know that then such semigroup is of the form $e^{tA}$, for bounded $A$ and since the generator is unique we can conclude. It may help to use the fact that, if we call $T(t)$ the generated semigroup, we now that

$$\forall x\in X\;\;\; A\int_0^s T(s)xds=T(t)x-x,$$

since showing uniform continuity amounts to show that $||T(t)-I|| \rightarrow 0^+$ in the operator norm, however this puts me in a vicious cycle since what we need is precisely a bound on the norm of $A$.

2. Another property I’ve seen is that the image of $T(t)$ is contained in $D(A)$, thus if we show that $T(t)$ is surjective (in particular invertible) we can conclude immediately. Now, in the context of $C_0$-semigroups I would simply note that $A$ actually generates a group, i.e. $-A$ generates the semigroup $T(-t)=T(t)^{-1}$ but, after doing some research, I was surprised to not found a single piece of literature on “Analytic Groups of Operators”. This makes me think that this approach won’t work, at least not that straight-forwardly, to show that $T(t)$ is invertible (which it must be, since a uniform semigroup is actually a group of operators).

Do you have any idea on how to conclude one of this approaches? A new approach would of course be welcome too!

Comment: Your definition of sectorial operator is incomplete, I think. You're missing a condition on the norm of resolvent. Anyway, I don't quite understand where you are stuck with approach 2. Can you show that the semigroups $(S_t)$ and $(T_t)$ generated by $A$ and $-A$, respectively, satisfy $S_t T_t=T_t S_t=\mathrm{id}$?

Comment: @MaoWao Honestly no, the semigroups are given by some line integral and I’m not quite sure on how to compute their product. I’ll add some computations later if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(S_t)$ and $(T_t)$ be the semigroups generated by $A$ and $-A$, respectively. As both of them are analytic, they map $X$ into $D(A)$ for $t>0$ and commute with $A$. If $\xi\in X$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}S_tT_t\xi=AS_t T_t\xi-S_tAT_t\xi=0
$$
for $t>0$. Thus $S_tT_t=\mathrm{id}_X$. The proof of $T_t S_t=\mathrm{id}_X$ is analogous. Thus $S_t$ is invertible for every $t>0$. Since $S_t(X)\subset D(A)$, this implies $D(A)=X$. By the closed graph theorem, $A$ must hence be bounded.

Comment: A doubt arose in my mind when rewriting this, when you take the derivative aren’t you implicitly assuming that the semigroup is uniformly continuous?

Comment: No, what I use is that sectorial operator generate analytic semigroups, and these are immediately differentiable (i.e. $t\mapsto T_t\xi$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$). Alternatively you can also make the same computation for $\xi\in D(A)$ first and use boundedness of $S_t$ and $T_t$ to extend the identities $S_t T_t\xi=\xi$ and $T_t S_t\xi=\xi$ to all of $X$.